# XSLT 1.0 sort elements

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
    <object>Clutch</object>
    <object>Gearbox</object>
    <object>Cylinder head</object>
    <object>Starter</object>
    <object>Airbox</object>
    <object>Inlet manifold</object>
</objects>
```

And the following XSLT document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="objects">
        <parts>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="object"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </parts>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="object">
        <part>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </part>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied I am getting the following output as expected, but it is not being sorted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parts>
    <part>Clutch</part>
    <part>Gearbox</part>
    <part>Cylinder head</part>
    <part>Starter</part>
    <part>Airbox</part>
    <part>Inlet manifold</part>
</parts>
```

Why is the `<xsl:sort select="object"/>` not being applied ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The reason is here:**

> ```
>       <parts>
>           <xsl:apply-templates>
>               <xsl:sort select="object"/>
>           </xsl:apply-templates>
>       </parts>
> ```

This applies templates to the children (`object`) of the current node (`objects`) and sorts them by the string value of their first `object` child.

However in the provided XML document an `object` doesn't have any `object` children -- so they all have the same sort-key -- the empty string -- and their original order isn't changed by the sort operation.

**Solution**:

```
        <parts>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </parts>
```

**The complete transformation becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="objects">
    <parts>
     <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="."/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
    </parts>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="object">
  <part>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </part>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when it is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<objects>
    <object>Clutch</object>
    <object>Gearbox</object>
    <object>Cylinder head</object>
    <object>Starter</object>
    <object>Airbox</object>
    <object>Inlet manifold</object>
</objects>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<parts>
   <part>Airbox</part>
   <part>Clutch</part>
   <part>Cylinder head</part>
   <part>Gearbox</part>
   <part>Inlet manifold</part>
   <part>Starter</part>
</parts>
```

Comment: thanks for this. I'm having problems with my actual code though and though that using this example would help me. Any chance you could take a look, eventhough I've actually got it working now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523678/xslt-1-0-sort-on-filtered-xml-data

Comment: @generalexception: I am at work -- will have a look in  7 - 8 hours.