# XSLT 1.0 sort on filtered XML data

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting, xslt-1.0

Ok so based on this question [XSLT 1.0 sort elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522925/xslt-1-0-sort-elements) I cannot figure out why the following is not working:

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<viewentries>
    <viewentry>
        <entrydata name="Waste">
            <text>Bric-a-Brac</text>
        </entrydata>
        <entrydata name="Disposal">
            <text/>
        </entrydata>
    </viewentry>
    <viewentry>
        <entrydata name="Waste">
            <textlist>
                <text>Paper</text>
                <text>Glass</text>
            </textlist>
        </entrydata>
        <entrydata name="Disposal">
            <text/>
        </entrydata>
    </viewentry>
        <viewentry>
        <entrydata name="Waste">
            <textlist>
                <text>Paper</text>
                <text>Cans</text>
            </textlist>
        </entrydata>
        <entrydata name="Disposal">
                <text>Washing Machines</text>
                <text>Cars</text>
        </entrydata>
    </viewentry>
</viewentries>
```

And the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="k1" match="entrydata[@name = 'Waste' or @name = 'Disposal']//text" use="concat(ancestor::entrydata/@name, '|', .)"/>

    <xsl:template match="viewentries">
        <categories>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </categories>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="viewentry">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entrydata[@name =  'Waste' or @name = 'Disposal']//text
      [generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', concat(ancestor::entrydata/@name, '|', .))[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text[normalize-space() != '']">
        <category type="{ancestor::entrydata/@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </category>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories>
    <category type="Waste">Bric-a-Brac</category>
    <category type="Waste">Glass</category>
    <category type="Waste">Paper</category>
    <category type="Waste">Cans</category>
    <category type="Disposal">Cars</category>
    <category type="Disposal">Washing Machines</category>
</categories>
```

I need the output in sorted order:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories>
    <category type="Waste">Bric-a-Brac</category>
    <category type="Waste">Cans</category>
    <category type="Disposal">Cars</category>
    <category type="Waste">Glass</category>
    <category type="Waste">Paper</category>
    <category type="Disposal">Washing Machines</category>
</categories>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT:**

It seems to be sorting based on the first `<text>` value of `<entrydata>` only instead of all `<text>` values.

However this stylesheet works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="k1" match="entrydata[@name = 'Waste' or @name = 'Disposal']//text" use="concat(ancestor::entrydata/@name, '|', .)"/>

    <xsl:template match="viewentries">
        <categories>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="viewentry/entrydata[@name =  'Waste' or @name = 'Disposal']//text
            [generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', concat(ancestor::entrydata/@name, '|', .))[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="."/>          
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </categories>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text[normalize-space() != '']">
        <category type="{ancestor::entrydata/@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </category>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone explain why the first example doesn't work but the second example does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why applying the sort to the first template works,
>   but when applying it to the second template like in my original
>   question it doesn't ????

Here is your "second template":

```
<xsl:template match="text[normalize-space() != '']">
    <category type="{ancestor::entrydata/@name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="."/>            
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </category>
</xsl:template>
```

Here you want to sort the children of the current node by their string value.

However, in the provided XML document any `text` element has a single text-node child -- therefore there isn't anything to sort!

In this and in the previous question you commit the same error -- trying to sort the children of the elements that must be sorted -- you are sorting too-late.

**Remember**:

```
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
```

**is an abbreviation for**:

```
   <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
```

So, this means: apply templates to my children" -- not "apply templates to me".

**Update**: Here is a correct solution to the problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCatVal" match="text[text()]" use="concat(../@name, '+', .)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <categories>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "//text[generate-id()
               =
                generate-id(key('kCatVal',
                                 concat(../@name, '+', .)
                                 )[1]
                            )
                ]">
          <xsl:sort/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </categories>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text">
        <category type="{../@name}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></category>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<viewentries>
    <viewentry>
        <entrydata name="Waste">
            <text>Bric-a-Brac</text>
        </entrydata>
        <entrydata name="Disposal">
            <text/>
        </entrydata>
    </viewentry>
    <viewentry>
        <entrydata name="Waste">
            <textlist>
                <text>Paper</text>
                <text>Glass</text>
            </textlist>
        </entrydata>
        <entrydata name="Disposal">
            <text/>
        </entrydata>
    </viewentry>
    <viewentry>
        <entrydata name="Waste">
            <textlist>
                <text>Paper</text>
                <text>Cans</text>
            </textlist>
        </entrydata>
        <entrydata name="Disposal">
            <text>Washing Machines</text>
            <text>Cars</text>
        </entrydata>
    </viewentry>
</viewentries>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<categories>
   <category type="Waste">Bric-a-Brac</category>
   <category type="">Cans</category>
   <category type="Disposal">Cars</category>
   <category type="">Glass</category>
   <category type="">Paper</category>
   <category type="Disposal">Washing Machines</category>
</categories>
```

**Explanation**:

This kind of grouping requires indexing based on a composite key that has two parts. Therefore the `use` attribute of `xsl:key` is specified as the concatenation of these two parts, joined together by a character that we know cannot be present in any of their values (to avoid false-positives when a value of the first key component is a prefix of a value of the second key component).

Comment: Ok I understand this, so my <text> elements are part of <entrydata>, I therefore need to sort here. The issue seems to be, that if i sort here, it is only selecting the first <text> element if <entrydata> has more than one of them.

Comment: @generalexception: I updated the answer with a complete solution. This problem requires indexing by composite keys.